# WPF ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay doesn't work

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I have noticed that ToolTipServices.BetweenShowDelay doesn't work as expected.
Also, I found the same [question](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623656/tooltipservices-betweenshowdelay-doesnt-work#details)

STR:
1. Create a WPF application in VS2010.
2. Add two buttons to the WPF window, which are 




3. Run the application, and move mouse from one button to the other.

Actual Result:
Tooltips show up with no delay when I move mouse from one button to the other.

Expected result:
Tooltips should show up with the initial delay.

Comment: It seems to happen when the mouse pointer doesn't get to pass over another element. It seems like it doesn't reinitialize the tooltip's internal timer.

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9fc882e7-04a9-4fd6-b1c9-a16acbf25c1d/tooltipservicebetweenshowdelay-still-not-working-after-9-years?forum=wpf